# How to get mouse position in a window with Python?

Tags: python, interface, 3d-view

I want to detect if the mouse is in certain area of the 3d View, so I can display a custom menu when it will be in the left top corner, over the view name ("User Persp" etc).

Comment: Take a look at the python templates, some of them use the mouse position, such as the Modal Draw template that draws the path of mouse: http://i.imgur.com/55rYdAc.png

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here is a script from the [blender wiki](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:2.5/Py/Scripts/Cookbook/Code_snippets/Interface).

Go to the *Invoke versus execute* section for finding this code:

```
#----------------------------------------------------------
# File invoke.py
# from API documentation
#----------------------------------------------------------
 
import bpy
 
class SimpleMouseOperator(bpy.types.Operator):
    """ This operator shows the mouse location,
        this string is used for the tooltip and API docs
    """
    bl_idname = "wm.mouse_position"
    bl_label = "Mouse location"
 
    x: bpy.props.IntProperty()
    y: bpy.props.IntProperty()
 
    def execute(self, context):
        # rather then printing, use the report function,
        # this way the message appears in the header,
        self.report({'INFO'}, "Mouse coords are %d %d" % (self.x, self.y))
        return {'FINISHED'}
 
    def invoke(self, context, event):
        self.x = event.mouse_x
        self.y = event.mouse_y
        return self.execute(context)
 
#
#    Panel in tools region
#
class MousePanel(bpy.types.Panel):
    bl_label = "Mouse"
    bl_space_type = "VIEW_3D"
    bl_region_type = "TOOL_PROPS"
 
    def draw(self, context):
        self.layout.operator("wm.mouse_position")
 
#
#   Registration
#   Not really necessary to register the class, because this happens
#   automatically when the module is registered. OTOH, it does not hurt either.
bpy.utils.register_class(SimpleMouseOperator)
bpy.utils.register_module(__name__)
 
# Automatically display mouse position on startup
bpy.ops.wm.mouse_position('INVOKE_DEFAULT')
 
# Another test call, this time call execute() directly with pre-defined settings.
#bpy.ops.wm.mouse_position('EXEC_DEFAULT', x=20, y=66)
```

Now if you want to know the position of your 3D view, I made a quick research. With this you can find the area of your 3D View:

```
import bpy

for area in bpy.context.screen.areas:
    if area.type=='VIEW_3D':
        X= area.x
        Y= area.y
        WIDTH=area.width
        HEIGHT=area.height
        
        print(X,Y,WIDTH,HEIGHT)
```

Comment: Thanks, now I guess I need to get the position and size of the 3d View, to determine if the mouse is in the specified location or not. The sidebar also adds trouble.

Comment: I've edited my answer. At the end you will find how to determine the size and position of the 3D View.

Comment: That's great, works, thanks! Any way to determine the sidebar current width? If I can get that, I will be able to do what I want.

Comment: I don't know how to determinate that. Ask it at an other question, you will find better help :)

Answer (score 6):

You get the area and the region from the [context](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_71_0/bpy.types.Context.html#bpy.types.Context)
argument (passed to the invoke / execute / poll method of the operator).

Use the operator's [poll](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_71_0/bpy.types.Operator.html?highlight=bpy.types.operator#bpy.types.Operator.poll)
method to check for the right context. I.e:

```
@classmethod
def poll(cls, context):
    return context.area.type   == 'VIEW_3D' and \
           context.region.type == 'WINDOW'
```

Just want to add:

- The [event class](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_71_0/bpy.types.Event.html#module-bpy.types)
  also provides the attributes 
  [mouse_region_x](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_71_0/bpy.types.Event.html#bpy.types.Event.mouse_region_x)
  and
  [mouse_region_y](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_71_0/bpy.types.Event.html#bpy.types.Event.mouse_region_y)
- The [view2d class](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_71_0/bpy.types.View2D.html#bpy.types.View2D) 
  provides methods to convert mouse coordinates from region coordinates to view coordinates
- The [bpy_extras.view3d_utils](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_71_0/bpy_extras.view3d_utils.html#module-bpy_extras.view3d_utils)
  module provides methods to deal with 3d-coordinates

Comment: Do you mean poll for the operator or the panel?