# Is there a way to determine the left 3D view sidebar's current width with python?

Tags: python, interface

I want to display a custom menu when it will be in the left top corner of the 3D View, over the view name ("User Persp" etc).

I guess this is the long way, but if I'll also know the window location and area (already answered here [How to get mouse position in a window with Python?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/13450/how-to-get-mouse-position-in-a-window-with-python#13451)), and mouse position, then I'll be able to calculate if the mouse is in the right spot or not.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can query the region's width from [bpy.types.Region.width](https://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_77a_release/bpy.types.Region.html#bpy.types.Region.width)

I'm not sure if the toolbar region is always the second region (`region[1]`) in the [bpy.types.Area.regions](https://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_77a_release/bpy.types.Area.html#bpy.types.Area.regions) list, but you can always just loop through and check the type:

```
for region in bpy.context.area.regions:
    if region.type == "TOOLS":
        width = region.width
        break
```

That'll pick the first region of type `TOOLS`, though afaik there can be only one.