# Find the width of T panel

Tags: python, scripting

Is it possible to find the width of the T panel when this one is displayed ?
For an addon, i display some text whith blf module on the bottom left side of the 3d view. 
If i activate the overlap of the T panel, the text go behind the panel, so i have to know the panel width to put the text correctly.
Does anyone have a solution please ?

Comment: Possible duplicate [Is there a way to determine the left 3D view sidebar's current width with python?](http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/13456/2271)