# Get width of properties panel

Tags: python

How do I get the width of the <kbd>N</kbd> Properties Panel in the *3D View* using the Python API of **Blender 2.8**?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

**`Area.width`**

The screen is made up of areas, each area has an `x, y, width, height` attribute.

Python console test code:

```
>>> for a in C.screen.areas:
...     a.type, a.width
...     
('PROPERTIES', 346)
('CONSOLE', 931)
('VIEW_3D', 346)
('TEXT_EDITOR', 931)
```

**`Region.width`**

within each area there are regions. Commonly there are `'HEADER', 'UI', 'TOOLS'` and `'WINDOW'` regions.  For the `'VIEW_3D'` region the N panel is region type  `'UI'`

```
>>> for a in C.screen.areas:
...     if a.type == 'VIEW_3D':
...         break
...         
>>> a.type
'VIEW_3D'

>>> for r in a.regions:
...     r.type, r.width
...     
('HEADER', 931)
('TOOLS', 1)
('UI', 335)
('WINDOW', 931)
```

If you are writing UI code to go in the N panel then can get the width directly with

```
context.region.width
```

Related:

[Is there a way to determine the left 3D view sidebar's current width with python?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/13456/is-there-a-way-to-determine-the-left-3d-view-sidebars-current-width-with-python)

Comment: I would never have thought that this panel is called 'UI'. Thank.