# How to get a right click coordinates in 3d_view

Tags: python, scripting, coordinates

I'm listening to the right click in my model operator. I wish to get its 3D coordinates in the 3D_view. I've tried the following code from [here](https://blenderartists.org/forum/archive/index.php/t-247286.html):

```
from bpy_extras.view3d_utils import region_2d_to_vector_3d, region_2d_to_location_3d
def mouse_coo_to_3d_loc(event, context):
    coord = (event.mouse_region_x, event.mouse_region_y)
    region = context.region
    rv3d = context.space_data.region_3d
    vec = region_2d_to_vector_3d(region, rv3d, coord)
    return region_2d_to_location_3d(region, rv3d, coord, vec)
```

But I got different coordinates from bpy.context.scene.cursor_location. I thought that maybe the context is wrong, so I used this code instead:

```
def mouse_coo_to_3d_loc(event):
    area, region = get_3d_area_region()
    coord = (event.mouse_x - area.x, event.mouse_y - area.y)
    rv3d = area.spaces.active.region_3d
    vec = region_2d_to_vector_3d(region, rv3d, coord)
    return region_2d_to_location_3d(region, rv3d, coord, vec)

def get_3d_area_region():
    for screen in bpy.data.screens:
        for area in screen.areas:
            if area.type == 'VIEW_3D':
                for region in area.regions:
                    if region.type == 'WINDOW':
                        return area, region
```

But still wrong results. Am I m missing something here?

**** EDIT ****

I should have mentioned that my addon is running in the graph_editor.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/13450/how-to-get-mouse-position-in-a-window-with-python/13501#13501

Comment: What is the issue here? [the code](https://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?247286-mouse-coordinate-to-view-3d-coordinate&p=2067020&viewfull=1#post2067020) works as described.  Invoke the operator via button or space bar in 3d view.  Substituting setting the cursor location instead of moving context object sets the cursor location as expected.  What's the point of `get_3d_area_region()` above? will always return the `VIEW_3D` area  of `bpy.data.screens[0]` .. (or first with 3d view,  eg  "3D Full VIew" screen  in default file.)

Comment: Ah, sorry, I should have mentioned that my addon is running in the graph_editor. That might be the reason.

Answer (score 1):

**Get screen from `context.screen` or `context.window.screen`**

Get the clicked area by looking at area coordinates, of each area, in the screen returned from `context.screen` or `context.window.screen`. Used the latter in example below, my tests suggest could use either.   The region can be obtained from the area.

```
    if event.type == 'RIGHTMOUSE' and event.value == 'PRESS':
        screen = context.window.screen # or context.screen
        def get_click_area():            
            for a in screen.areas:
                if (a.x < event.mouse_x < a.x + a.width
                and a.y < event.mouse_y < a.y + a.height):
                    return a
        a = get_click_area()
        print("Right Clicked in %s area of screen %s" % (a.type, screen.name))
```

as mentioned in my comment, `get_3d_area_region()` above, will only return the first matching area it finds in the `bpy.data.screens` collection. For the default file will be `bpy.data.screens["3D Full View"].areas[1]` every time.