# Get which `area` is active (from within the VIEW_3D context)

Tags: python, scripting, interface

I have a panel with a label inside the 3d viewport and I want to change the text of the label depending on if the mouse cursor is in the `VIEW_3D` area or not. I don't have an operator so I can't use invoke and using `bpy.context.area.type` from within the panel will always return `VIEW_3D` since that's the panels context.

This code doesn't work but is essentially what I'd like to be able to do:

```
import bpy


class HelloWorldPanel(bpy.types.Panel):
    """Creates a Panel in the Object properties window"""
    bl_label = "Hello World Panel"
    bl_idname = "OBJECT_PT_hello"
    bl_space_type = 'VIEW_3D'
    bl_region_type = 'UI'
    bl_category = "Custom Panel"

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout

        if bpy.context.area.type == 'VIEW_3D':
            row = layout.row()
            row.label(text="Focused")
        else:
            row = layout.row()
            row.label(text="Panel not in focus")


def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(HelloWorldPanel)


def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(HelloWorldPanel)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

[Short video showing how I'd like it to work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pb8qh.jpg)

From the context of the panel inside the 3d viewport, is there any way to tell if the mouse is outside the `VIEW_3D` area? I'd like to change a label if the cursor is in the 3d viewport.

Comment: Can you define what you mean by *"active"*?

Comment: When a panel is draw the context area is always the one it's drawn in. Do you mean you want to know when the user hovers their mouse over different parts of the UI ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get mouse position in a window with Python?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/13450/how-to-get-mouse-position-in-a-window-with-python)

Comment: @pyCod3R ISTM that isn't the answer the OP was looking for, because they needed the extra knowledge that their solution required access to the mouse position.

Comment: @MarkusvonBroady @Gorgious sorry for the confusion, I edited the post for clarity. What I meant was for the panel to show a label depending on if the mouse cursor is inside or outside the `VIEW_3D` area

Answer (score 2):

If you define "active" as "cursor is in the area", then you need to have an actual test for where the mouse is.  Here's a demonstration of an operator that figures out if the mouse is in the 3D Viewport.  You need to modify it so that it puts the value somewhere appropriate to your needs rather than just reporting it.  You then need to invoke it and use that value in your if test.  The panel is only present as a demonstration, and you don't need it.

```py
import bpy

def is_in_view3d_area(x,y):
    for area in bpy.context.screen.areas:
        if area.type == "VIEW_3D":
            x_in_range = x >= area.x and x <= area.x + area.width
            y_in_range = y >= area.y and y <= area.y + area.height
            return x_in_range and y_in_range
    return False

class SimpleMouseOperator(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname = "wm.mouse_position"
    bl_label = "Mouse location"

    x : bpy.props.IntProperty()
    y : bpy.props.IntProperty()

    def execute(self, context):
        # rather then printing, use the report function,
        # this way the message appears in the header,
        in_range = is_in_view3d_area(self.x, self.y)
        self.report({'INFO'}, "Mouse coords are %d %d" % (self.x, self.y))
        self.report({'INFO'}, f"{in_range}")
        return {'FINISHED'}

    def invoke(self, context, event):
        self.x = event.mouse_x
        self.y = event.mouse_y
        return self.execute(context)

class MousePanel(bpy.types.Panel):
    bl_label = "Mouse"
    bl_space_type = "VIEW_3D"
    bl_region_type = "UI"

    def draw(self, context):
        self.layout.operator("wm.mouse_position")

bpy.utils.register_class(SimpleMouseOperator)
bpy.utils.register_class(MousePanel)

bpy.ops.wm.mouse_position('INVOKE_DEFAULT')
```

The key take away is that the operator relies on the `invoke` function having an event with the mouse coordinates.  `is_in_view3d_area` has to be called in the operator, since the 3D Viewport could have been resized since it was last called.  It does assume you only have one 3D viewport.  If you want to check any of several possible viewport areas than its logic has to change.

Comment: I'm sure you know this but I'll plug it anyways for completeness :) , in python you can chain comparison operators : `x < y < z` is the same as `y > x and y < z` https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#comparisons

Comment: Actually that's one I missed when I was learning python.  Thanks for the heads up.

Comment: `x : bpy.props.IntProperty(), y : bpy.props.IntProperty()`

Comment: @pyCod3R good spot.  fixed.

Comment: `is_in_view3d_area(context, x, y); for area in context.screen.areas:`

Comment: @pyCod3R I'd like to see the reasoning here, why not use the global? To allow context override?

Comment: Yeah I guess it really matters if you're going to override the operator or call the script from the command line ?

Comment: @MarkusvonBroady If you are hanging out with a friend at a party, why would you go outside, call your friend and invite him again?

Comment: @pyCod3R why would give your friend a different name just for the party, rather than using the name you know him by from outside the party? Your analogy is a double-edged sword... :)

Comment: @Gorgious in this specific case, though, it doesn't make sense to call the script from the command line. Probably safe to assume context overriding isn't important for cursor checking as well...

Comment: I don't have an operator that I call, I just have a panel and would like for the panel to display text based on if the mouse cursor is inside or outside the `VIEW_3D` area.

Comment: @CybranM  What I'm suggesting is that in your panel you call the operator I described and use its result in the if statement.

Comment: @pyCod3R  I would go outside because the parties I go to are too noise to make phone calls from. (and yes, I'm being silly here.)

Comment: @MartyFouts If I try to call the operator from the panel is gives me a runtime error: `RuntimeError: Calling operator "bpy.ops.wm.mouse_position" error, can't modify blend data in this state (drawing/rendering)`
I want to enable/disable part of the UI based off the active area (mouse position) but it doesnt seem like I can call the operator from inside the panel.

Comment: @CybranM I'm not getting that error.  Perhaps add a blend file to your question that shows the problem?  I'll look at it and see what needs to be modified in my code to work in your context.

Comment: @MartyFouts Uploaded an edited code sample to [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/MM64Vgar). The problem is I have a function that only works in the 3d viewport (I'm checking UV coords which breaks the UV editor if you try to edit the UVs and have the function enabled) so I need to turn it off if the cursor moves outside the 3d view